# Change colour of flush list line break in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using the example from the docs:

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

How would I change the line colour? I'm using a dark background and it's blending in [extremely well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfgIT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check a couple of options:

1.If you are using SCSS and have a `variables.scss` then you can simply overwrite this variable with your preferred shade:

```
$list-group-border-color: #999;
```

2.If you have only CSS then it's time to just overwrite that particular border like so:

```
.list-group-item {
    border-color: #999;
}
```